# Output type is currently not supported when using pycharm/jupyter/hvplot

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter, hvplot

I am using jupyter with pycharm. When I try to plot data with hvplot, I get an error saying "Output type is currently not supported". I assume pycharm doesn't support javascript. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?
My code is like this:

```
import pandas
import hvplot.pandas

df = pd.read_csv(fle)
df.hvplot(x='x label', y=['y label 1', 'y label 2'])
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is obsolete in PyCharm 2021.3 where the new Jupyter support is introduced. Here is the corresponding ticket https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-48538.

2021.3 Release Candidate (RC) is available here https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/